# wix: Display error message box when click Repair from context Menu

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am creating an installer in wix. When the user right-clicks the MSI and selects Repair option, I want to display message box with an error.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't know what triggers a repair. So you cannot handle the context menu option. You can handle only the repair operation, no matter what triggered it.

To detect a repair you can use the [REINSTALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property.